# Laravel 5.4 session is not being set if dd method is used

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4. In a method of a controller I have setting a value in session. If I call the `dd()` right after setting the session the `dd()` is showing all the session with the session I have just set. But if I fetch the session from another method the session is not available. If I remove the `dd()` from session setter method, I am getting the session properly.

My Code is as below:

```
public class TestController{
  public function setSession(){
    session(['test_key' => 'test_value']);//setting up the session
    dd(session()->all());//getting the session properly here
  }

  public function showSession(){
    dd(session()->all());//Here we are not getting the session
  }
}
```

If we remove the `dd()` from `setSession()` session it works properly.  Is it a bug of Laravel or it's intentional. I am interested to know the root cause of this fact. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`dd()` means "dump & die" and uses `die()` in its implementation, which immediately terminates the framework and does not allow Laravel to correctly complete the request and save the session. You can use `dump()` to display information like `dd()` does and do not shut down the kernel after.

Comment: Hasn't the `session()` method already saved the value to session just before `dd()` called? What else operation is required to complete it's implementation.

Comment: No, Laravel first collects all the data that needs to be written to the session, and saves them after the user code is executed. However, you can force the session to be saved immediately: `session(['key' => 'value']); session()->save();`

Comment: The reason for this is that session data is written through `Terminable Middleware`. This is what @Anton is describing.

Comment: ooh, I see. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Is there any reference about this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove  this line `dd(session()->all())`

from setSession() and try it again.

Comment: I know it work after removing this line. But my question is why this is not working? I am just dumping the session here right?

Comment: yeah, you are right.  dd means dump and die that you already know.  ):